# pitest doesn't find tests

Tags: maven, testing, pitest

I am facing a problem with the SonarQube project. I want to calculate some statistics about test quality and I am using pitest. Unfortunately, it doesn't find any test to mutate.

This is the *pom.xml* of the module that I am analyzing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonarqube</artifactId>
    <version>6.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>sonar-core</artifactId>

  <name>SonarQube :: Core</name>
  <description>Library shared by analyzer and server</description>

  <properties>
    <sonar.exclusions>target/generated-sources/**/*,target/generated-test-sources/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
      <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-classloader</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.update-center</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-update-center-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <!-- sonar-api-deps.jar is copied into target JAR file -->
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api-deps</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- tests -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-testing-harness</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.bean-matchers</groupId>
      <artifactId>bean-matchers</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.21</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.basepom.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>duplicate-finder-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <ignoredDependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api-deps</artifactId>
              </dependency>
            </ignoredDependencies>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
          <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.10</version>
          <configuration>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
              <targetClasses>
                  <param>org.sonar.core.*</param>
              </targetClasses>
              <targetTests>
                  <param>org.sonar.core.*</param>
              </targetTests>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-deprecated-api-deps</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                  <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api-deps</artifactId>
                  <destFileName>sonar-plugin-api-deps.jar</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

But when I run:

```
mvn clean install org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage
```

it doesn't find tests, namely:

```
4:16:26 PM PIT >> INFO : Sending 0 test classes to minion
4:16:26 PM PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
4:16:27 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:16:27 PM PIT >> INFO : Checking environment

4:16:27 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:16:27 PM PIT >> INFO : Found  0 tests

4:16:27 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:16:27 PM PIT >> INFO : Dependency analysis reduced number of potential tests by 0

4:16:27 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 4:16:27 PM PIT >> INFO : 0 tests received
```

PS: the tests in maven are correctly executed:

```
Results :

Tests run: 402, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

What am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You specified for the pitest plugin

```
<targetClasses>
  <param>org.sonar.core.*</param>
</targetClasses>
<targetTests>
  <param>org.sonar.core.*</param>
</targetTests>
```

Did you check, you have test classes in those packages?